# Differences between StandardNaiveBayesClassifier and ComplementaryNaiveBayesClassifier in mahout

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, mahout

Maybe my question is quite sophisticated, but I would like to know the main differences between `StandardNaiveBayesClassifier` and `ComplementaryNaiveBayesClassifier` algorithms in `Mahout`. Which one performs better on smaller amount of training data or it is data dependent issue? Which one is better for sentiment analysis? And some other aspecs...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Complement naive Bayes](http://people.csail.mit.edu/~jrennie/papers/icml03-nb.pdf) is an naive Bayes variant that tends to work better than the vanilla version when the classes in the training set are imbalanced. In short, it estimates feature probabilities for each class *y* based on the *complement* of *y*, i.e. on *all other* classes' samples, instead of on the training samples of class *y* itself.

Comment: Thank you for excellent whitepaper, here are the main points:


One systemic problem is that when one class has more training examples than an other, Naive Bayes selects poor weights for the decision boundary. This is due to under-studied bias effect that shrinks weights for classes with few training examples. 
To balance the amount of training examples used per estimate, we introduce a "complement class" formulation of Naive Bayes.
The complement estimates mitigate the problem of the skewed data bias

Comment: Another systematic problem with Nayve Bayes is that features assumed to be independent. As a result, even when words are dependent, each word contributes evidence individually. Thus the magnitude of the weights for classes with strong word dependencies is larger than for classes with weak word dependencies. 
To keep classes with more dependencies from domintating, we normalize the classification weights.
In estimating weights for regular MNB we use training data from a single class, c. In contrast, CNB estimates parameters using data from all classes except c.

Comment: @elkoo: I was a bit lazy; I put a very short summary in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Compliment Naive Bayes (CNB) classifier improves upon the weakness of the Naive Bayes classifier by estimating parameters from data in all sentiment classes except the one which we are evaluating for.

Answer (score 0):

1) Even though performance of the NaïveBayes is good it makes several poor assumptions such as data independence and the uneven training
data for a particular class (skewed data).
2)Complemented Naïve Bayes is one of the NaïveBayes variant which tackles the poor assumptions made by the parent Naïve Bayes classifier such as the Uneven Training size (The most occurring class in training data dominates during actual
classification) and the independence (All features or attributes are treated individually) assumptions.Skewed data refers to having more training examples for one class than another which causes the decision boundary weights to be biased. This in turn induces the classifier to unwittingly prefer one class
over the other. To counter this problem Complement Naïve Bayes proposes a probability estimate parameter which uses data from all classes except c